# collectionview scrollToItemAtIndexPath is not working with pagination

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

```
//Scroll to top
NSIndexPath *index=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.collectionview scrollToItemAtIndexPath:index atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

I tried this code but it is not working

```
[self.collectionview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,250) animated:YES];
```

with this code also the same result only

Comment: chnage position for top: UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop

Comment: @vijeesh are you using horizontal pagination or vertical pagination?